# How I can enable intellisense in JB Rider for Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, linux, xamarin.forms, rider

I built a xamarin-android project on ubuntu (maybe broke something), then created a Xamarin.Forms project from a template.
The rider cannot load any of the assemblies (including System):

[can't load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dldVI.png)

❯ which dotnet 
/usr/bin/dotnet

❯ dotnet --version 
5.0.201

❯ which mono 
/usr/bin/mono
❯ mono -V 
Mono JIT compiler version 6.12.0.122 (tarball Mon Feb 22 17:33:28 UTC 2021)

❯ /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.201 
❯ ll | grep MSBuild.dll 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 733K фев 24 05:49 MSBuild.dll

Comment: It seems Rider was not able to find Xamarin SDK in the mono? Are you sure it is installed in a right way?

Comment: I'm not sure :)
After installing deps and `git clone https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android.git && cd xamarin-android && git submodule update --init --recursive && make prepare && make && sudo make install` I trying to build template project manually with `msbuild` and build was succesfull.
For now when I try to build it in rider i have  "/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.201/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets" not found ... error, and rider doesn't "see" even System assemblies

Comment: Probably Rider uses another msbuild or mono - without xamarin SDK inside. Go to `File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Toolset and Build` and check